# Allow only one digit numbers for input type number

Tags: angularjs

I have a number text box with min and max values.I given min="0" and max="9".But user can able to enter more than 9 like 10,100 etc..

```
<input style='width:125px;' ng-model='decimalvalues' min='0' max='9'
       ng-init='decimalvalues=4'
       data-ng-change=" + Decimalplaces + " 
       type='number'
       id='decimalvalues'/>"
```

Comment: What you have described should work.  Are you able to create a [mcve] - either in a snippet or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) - where the community can see the problem and understand how it might be resolved?

Comment: normally on key up and key down it is showing between 0 and 9,but on key press  user can enter more than 9

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is the default behavior of `min/max`. These attributes are used for **validation**, they can't prevent user from entering invalid values. If user enters a value bigger than `max`, form control becomes `$invalid` and `$error` object is filled with: `{"max":true}`. You can use that values to show an error message to user. (If you want to prevent user from entering a wrong value, then a custom directive is needed)

Read more here to understand how validation works:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$error

Check a working example with error messages: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b6w2nmrd/8/)

Also, you `ng-change` expression is invalid, you should remove or replace it.